# share folder not recognized for mpirun

Tags: mpi, openmpi, mpic++

I have successfully installed openmpi locally in a compute cluster (CentOS system) without sudo privileges.  So the location of installed openmpi is non-standard. Lets say the location of the installed file is `$/home/username/openmpi`. The `bin`, `lib`, `share`, `include` folders are in `openmpi` folder. For system to recognize `mpirun`, I have added the location of bin folder (`/home/username/openmpi/bin`) in `$PATH`, and lib folder to `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. However, the `share` folder is not recognized by mpirun binary and therefore it fails. So, to which environment variable should I add the share folder? Thank you in advance for your insights and help.

I get the following error when I run mpirun.

### `$mpirun

### Sorry!  You were supposed to get help about:
opal_init:startup:internal-failure
But I couldn't open the help file:
/usr/local/share/openmpi/help-opal-runtime.txt: No such file or directory.  Sorry!

The file `help-opal-runtime.txt` is located in `/home/username/openmpi/share/openmpi/`

Among the posts I have seen, they only recommend adding locations in `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, so I need some help figuring out how to correctly add paths in the environment variables so that the share folder is searchable.

I have also attempted adding `/home/username/openmpi` and `/home/username/openmpi/share/openmpi` to  `$PATH` but it does not solve the issue.

I have similar issues with mpicc, mpic++, etc.

`$mpicc
Cannot open configuration file /usr/local/share/openmpi/mpicc-wrapper-data.txt
Error parsing data file mpicc: Not found

$mpic++
Cannot open configuration file /usr/local/share/openmpi/mpic++-wrapper-data.txt
Error parsing data file mpic++: Not found`

Comment: How did you install Open MPI? 
did you `configure --prefix=/home/username/openmpi`

Comment: Based on the INSTALL file, i first ran `./autogen.pl` , then `./configure --prefix=/home/username/openmpi`. The version I installed is openmpi-4.1.2. I had gcc-10.1.0 and cuda-11.2 loaded. I had some other things loaded as well, although I don't think it is relevant here.

Comment: Edit: I checked the Makefile, it looks like i did not add --prefix, so I must have installed in in the directory using `make DESTDIR=/home/username/openmpi all install`. I will recompile and see if it works.

Comment: That should do the trick. Note you do not have to autogen.pl if you build from a tarball.

Comment: Yes. This solved the issue. Can you post is as an answer so I can accept it and mark it as resolved?